# Using 'Print Management' to remotely administer Windows 7 Pro machines

Tags: windows-7, printing, mmc, print-server

On my work network, we have the Domain Controller running Debian Wheezy, not Windows Server. I have about 250 Windows 7 Pro machines I manage. I know if I were to be using a Windows Server OS that I could connect to workstations via Print Management. I can connect right now via the Print Management MMC snap in, but I can't view any actual information, even though I'm using an administrator account.

I right-click on **Print Servers**, choose **Add/Remove Servers**, and add the remote computers. Right now, I'm trying just one at a time. If I then select *Drivers*, *Forms*, *Ports* or *Printers*, they just show an empty window on the right, reading `There are no items to show in this view`.

I can remotely push out software to systems, and I have the *Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)* and *File and Printer Sharing* exceptions made in the firewall. I can access the `C$` and `ADMIN$` shares from the same computer, so I know these are not being blocked.

What I want is to be able to manage printers on remote systems, without requiring the use of a Windows Server using Group Policies. I would prefer to do it without having to interrupt the current user's work, if possible. Can I do it?

**Edit**: I booted up a trial of Windows Server 2012 R2, added the Printer server role, and tried again. When I right-click, and choose Properties on the added machine, it says the Username and Password are incorrect. I opened the Command Prompt, and ran `net use \\MACHINENAME /user:Administrator <password>`, but no change.